# How to fix "the type name lerp or MoveForward does not exist in the type vector 3"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try and change `new Vector3.(x,y,z)` in the client object class to **`new Vector3.MoveTowards()`** and it tells

> *`the type name lerp or MoveForward does not exist in the type vector 3`*

I am using ZeroMQ to control a cube in unity and would like the cube to slowly move to the position next assigned to it.

Is this problem occuring because I do not have a speed set in my script?

I have tried changing the `var position` to **`float position`** but that didn't do the trick either.

```
public class ClientObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private NetMqListener _netMqListener;

    private void HandleMessage(string message)
    {
        var splittedStrings = message.Split(' ');
        if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
        var x = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
        var y = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
        var z = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
        transform.position = new Vector3.(x,y,z);
    }
}

public class ServerObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool Connected;
    private NetMqPublisher _netMqPublisher;
    private string _response;
    private Transform target;

    private void Start()
    {
        _netMqPublisher = new NetMqPublisher(HandleMessage);
        _netMqPublisher.Start();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var position = transform.position;
        _response = "{position.x} {position.y} {position.z}";
        Connected = _netMqPublisher.Connected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) and [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) are **`static`** methods.

You use them with the according class `Vector3` without a `new` keyword:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, targetPos, speed);
```

and

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, interpolationFactor);
```

---

I don't know the nature of this `HandleMessage` call but it seems to not get called repeatedly but only **once** so you might be interested in using a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g.

```
private void HandleMessage(string message)
{
    var splittedStrings = message.Split(' ');
    if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;

    // Here you probably wanted to use the correct indices!
    var x = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
    var y = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
    var z = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);

    // start a routine for smooth movement over time
    // either using a constant speed (units/second)
    StartCoroutine(MoveWithConstantSpeed(targetPos, 1f));

    // or with a dynamic velocity but a fixed duration (seconds)
    StartCoroutine(MoveWithConstantSpeed(targetPos, 1f));
}

// optional (but recommneded) a flag for skipping new movement 
// until the last one is finished
private bool isMoving;

private IEnumerator MoveInFixedDuration(Vector3 targetPos, float speed)
{
    // ignore if already moving to avoid concurrent routine
    if(isMoving) yield break;
    isMoving = true;

    while(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPos) > 0)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        // pause this routine, render the frame and continue from here
        // in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    isMoving = false;
}

private IEnumerator MoveInFixedDuration(Vector3 targetPos, float duration)
{
    // ignore if already moving to avoid concurrent routine
    if(isMoving) yield break;
    isMoving = true;

    var startPos = transform.position;

    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
        var factor = timePassed / duration;
        // optionally add ease-in and ease-out
        factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, factor);

        // increase by time passed since last frame, using Mathf.Min to avoid overshooting
        timePassed += Mathf.Min(Time.deltaTime, duration - timePassed);

        // pause this routine, render the frame and continue from here
        // in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    isMoving = false;
}
```

Comment: will I have to create these (startPos, endPos, interpolationFactor);

Comment: well yes ... they don't come out of nowhere ;) I just added an example using a Couroutine for a smooth movement invoked by the `HandleMessage` call - assuming this is a single time call

Comment: I cant explain how much of a help you are to me and the community, thank you again!